# Import and insert word in sequence in Python

Tags: python, import, webforms

I want to **import** and **insert** word in **sequence** and **NOT RANDOMLY**, each registration attempt uses a **single** username and **stop** until the registration is **completed**. Then logout and begin a **new** registration with the **next** username in the list if the **REGISTRATION is FAILED**, and **skip** if the **REGISTRATION is SUCCEDED**.

I'm really confused because I have no clue. I've tried this **code** but it chooses randomly and I have **no** idea how to use the "**for loop**"

```
import random

Copy = driver.find_element_by_xpath('XPATH')
Copy.click()
names = [
   "Noah" ,"Liam" ,"William" ,"Anthony" 
]
idx = random.randint(0, len(names) - 1)
print(f"Picked name: {names[idx]}")
Copy.send_keys(names[idx])
```

How can I make it choose the next word in sequence and **NOT RANDOMLY**
Any Help Please

Comment: Have you check this documentation? https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: its confusing; if you do not want to do it randomly, you can remove the random; i.e. do a click for each name instead.

Comment: doesn't work. I need the names to be imported in sequence. and I'll figure out how to loop them later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that you are happy with what the code does, with exception that the names it picks are random. This narrows everything down to one line, and namely the one that picks names randomly:

```
idx = random.randint(0, len(names) - 1)
```

Simple enough, you want "the next word in sequence and NOT RANDOMLY":
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

If you take a look at the link I've provided, you can see that lists have a ***pop()*** method, returning and removing some element from the list. We want the first one so we will provide 0 as the argument for the pop method.

We modify the line to look something like this

```
name = names.pop(0)
```

Now you still want to have the for-loop that will loop over all of the actions including name picking so you encapsulate all of the code in a for-loop:

```
names = [
    "Noah" ,"Liam" ,"William" ,"Anthony" 
]

for i in range(len(names)):
    # ...
    Copy = driver.find_element_by_xpath('XPATH')
    Copy.click()
    name = names.pop(0)
    print(f"Picked name: {name}")
    Copy.send_keys(name)
    # ...
```

You might notice that the names list is **not** inside the for-loop. That is because we don't want to reassign the list every time we try to use a new name.

If you're completely unsure how for-loops work or how to implement one yourself, you should probably start by reading about how they work.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=loop#for-statements

Last but not least you can see some `# ...` comments in my example indicating where the logic will probably go for the other part of your question: *"Then logout and begin a new registration with the next username in the list if the REGISTRATION is FAILED, and skip if the REGISTRATION is SUCCEDED."*